# My timer doesn't count properly

Tags: jquery

Currently working on a simple pomodoro clock, but I have encountered a problem that I can not solve. When you press the start button, the timer counts down the time, however, it changes the mode in 00:01, not 00:00 as it is. Can someone peek and suggest what causes this error?

```
  var flag = false;
  var timer;
  var work = 2;
  var count = 0;
  var breakTime = 3;
  var workTime = 4;
  var active = 'break';

  $('.mins').html(updateNum(work));
  $('.secs').html(updateNum(count));
  $('.session-minutes').html(work);

function workTimer() {

  if(count < 0) {
    work--;
    count = 2;
  }
  else if (work == 0 && count == 0) {

    if(active === 'work') {
      $(".timer-header").html('Work Time!');
      work = workTime;
      $('.mins').html(updateNum(work));
      return active = 'break';
    }
    if (active === 'break') {
      $(".timer-header").html('Break Time!');
      console.log(active);
      work = breakTime;
      $('.mins').html(updateNum(work));
      return active = 'work';
    }
  }

  $('.mins').html(updateNum(work));
  $('.secs').html(updateNum(count));
  count--;
}
$('.start-button').click(function() {
  if (flag == false) {

    timer=setInterval(workTimer,1000);
    $(this).html("stop");
    flag = true;
    return flag;
  }
  else if(flag == true){

      clearInterval(timer);
      $(this).html("start");
      flag = false;
      return flag;
  }
})

$('.reset-button').click(function() {
  if(flag == false) {
    work = 10;
    count = updateNum(0);
    $('.mins').html(work);
    $('.secs').html(count);
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

})

$('.session-plus').click(function() {
  if(flag == false) {
    if (work < 30) {
      $('.mins').html(updateNum(++work));
      $('.session-minutes').html(work);
    }

  }

})

$('.session-minus').click(function() {
  if(flag == false) {
    if (work > 1) {
      $('.mins').html(updateNum(--work));
      $('.session-minutes').html(work);
    }
  }

})

function updateNum(num) {
  if(num < 10 && num.length != 2) {
      return num = "0" + num;
  }
  else {
      return num;
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vnkgt3h/

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/6vnkgt3h/1/

Comment: Still the same problem. When the work mode ends, the break mode starts at 03:01, and should start at 03:00

Comment: Not sure what you mean, cant find any problems when i run the timer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6vnkgt3h/4/ Now it works OK, but can you look at this fiddle and tell me why the break mode don't change again to work mode? I was trying assign values to active var.

Comment: Mati, What is the point of you setting count back to 2 again.

Comment: When i run it and it hits break mode, it starts at 03:00 on mine

Comment: Because I do not want to wait a minute to see if my timer will work fine. He wants to work mode, break mode is activated, then work mode again and so on.

Comment: Yes, the timer now counts OK but does not return to work mode

Comment: Here, Problem was your 2 if statements, use else if - https://jsfiddle.net/6vnkgt3h/6/

Comment: Mati did i solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
if(count < 0) {
  work--;
  count = 2;
}
```

The correct would be: `count = 59;`

working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6vnkgt3h/1/)

Comment: The same problem appears. At this point I gave 2 seconds to just not wait for the change mode.